# Generating ed25519 keys in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, cryptography, ecdsa, ed25519

I am looking to generate ed25519 keys in java/kotlin. The key pair should be deterministic in that if one can provide some seed information used during the generation, they can generate the same pair again.

I understand one can achieve this using a mnemonic. Please advise me how to approach this. I am looking for a reputed library that can help me achieve this in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `libsodium`, here's a [link](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/) to the documentation.

`libsodium` is the most actively maintained implementation of [DJB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_J._Bernstein)'s [NaCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software)), thus if you are using `ed25519` or `curve25519` elliptic curve crypto, you should be using `libsodium`.

There are a [number](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) of bindings in `Java`/`Kotlin`.

It's really easy to use and it's safe, for example, it performs scalar multiplication in constant time.

To answer your question on determinism, libsodium provides a mechanism to generate deterministic keys from a seed. Note, you need to ensure your seed has sufficient entropy to be secure.

You should call `int crypto_sign_seed_keypair(unsigned char *pk, unsigned char *sk, const unsigned char *seed);` to [generate](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures#key-pair-generation) an ed25519 keypair from a seed.

[Here](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20boolean%20cryptoKxSeedKeypair(byte[]%20publicKey,%20byte[]%20secretKey,%20byte[]%20seed);) is a library that provides a binding to that function in Java:

```
    /**
     * Deterministically generate a public and secret key.
     * Store the seed somewhere if you want to generate these
     * keys again.
     * @param publicKey Public key will be populated here of size {@link #PUBLICKEYBYTES}.
     * @param secretKey Secret key will be populated here of size {@link #SECRETKEYBYTES}.
     * @param seed A random seed of size {@link #SEEDBYTES}.
     * @return True if generated successfully.
     */
    boolean cryptoKxSeedKeypair(byte[] publicKey, byte[] secretKey, byte[] seed);
```

Comment: Please, good fellow, library recommendations are off-topic. Please vote to close rather than answering the question. NOTE: I don't necessarily agree with this policy. I understand why they have it, but my experience is they do more good than harm.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I understand, apologies :+1